# SML - Error: operator is not a function [tycon mismatch]

Tags: sml

I'm trying to create a program that will sum the digits of a large factorial and this is what I'm doing:

```
fun sumDigits n = 
  if n < 10 then n
  else
    n mod 10 + sumDigits(n div 10)


fun factLarge 1 = IntInf.toLarge 1
  | factLarge n = IntInf.toLarge n * factLarge(n-1)


sumDigits (factLarge 100)
```

But I'm getting an error on `sumDigits (factLarge 100)` and I don't know how to fix it.

20.sml:8.19-11.26 Error: operator is not a function [tycon mismatch]
  operator: IntInf.int
  in expression:
    (factLarge (n - 1)) sumDigits

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That specific error is due to the way you must be pasting your code into the REPL. It can't figure out where the definition of `factLarge` ends. Put a semicolon at the end of that definition and this error will go away (or, even better use the command `use filename.sml;` rather than copy-pasting code):

```
fun sumDigits n = 
  if n < 10 then n
  else
    n mod 10 + sumDigits(n div 10);

fun factLarge 1 = IntInf.toLarge 1
  | factLarge n = IntInf.toLarge n * factLarge(n-1);

sumDigits (factLarge 100);
```

Unfortunately, this trades a superficial error for a deeper error:

```
stdIn:40.1-40.26 Error: operator and operand don't agree [tycon mismatch]
  operator domain: int
  operand:         IntInf.int
  in expression:
    sumDigits (factLarge 100)
```

The problem is that your `sumDigits` is expecting an `int`, not an `IntInf.int`. 
You have to put the appropriate type annotation on the definiton of `sumDigits` for this to work correctly. Since this seems to be homework, I'll leave it for you to work out.

Comment: An alternative to ending your declarations with `;` is to actually begin your value declarations with `val ... =`. For example, if you're going to run a function at top-level, `val it = sumDigits (factLarge 100)`.

Comment: Thank you! I've find out how to change sumDigits in a way that works.

`fun sumDigits n = 
  if n < 10 then IntInf.toLarge n
  else
    n mod 10 + sumDigits(IntInf.toLarge (n div 10));`